# sound detection accessing device node directly

Tags: bash-scripting, input-device, dev

I am attempting to invoke a bash action triggered by audio input. A very
simple sound detection sensor (no record) with adjustable threshold utilizing
a pc's onboard audio chipset and audio microphone would do the trick, something
like the perl script at
http://photodoto.com/index.php/2008/02/25/tethered-shooting-with-linux/
Nothing against perl, but I am hoping to eventually use this on a resource 
challenged hardware setup, so keeping things as close to the kernel and bash as possible
is imperative. Along those lines, solutions using ALSA and OSS are also out of the mix. 
Is it possible to make use of proc and/or device nodes via bash to accomplish this task? 
Thanks for any enlightenment.

Answer (score 0):

Not unless someone does a binary extension to `bash` to configure the audio device... that requires both the ability to handle random binary data and the ability to issue audio-device-specific `ioctl()` calls.

Comment: `dd bs=8k count=4 </dev/audio >testing-mic.raw` records 32768 bytes of audio

Comment: @cdaaawg, it does, at some default format/bit rate that you cannot control, and using that audio as a trigger (as per the OP's question) would be difficult from the shell.

Answer (score 0):

`dd bs=8k count=4 </dev/audio >testing-mic.raw` records 32768 bytes of audio, while `cat testing-mic.raw >/dev/audio` will playback that recorded audio. I am unsure of how to handle that raw audio file to get a baseline out of it though